# Executing with Appium server in Azure Pipelines using yaml file and console

Tags: powershell, android-studio, robotframework, azure-pipelines, appium-android

What is the best way to execute Appium server in Azure pipelines console using Microsoft hosted agent? Or is it even feasible? I´m using vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

I´ve managed to start the server with Cmdline and powershell script but I´m unsure if the server is actually running in the background.

So far I´ve tried -

1. Plain Cmdline script. "appium -p 4723". This starts the server but stays in the Cmdline job forever.
2. Plain Cmdline script with start call. "start appium -p 4723". I believe this would start Appium in another console, but I´m usure if the server keeps running in the background. Cmdline job passes to the next one. I don´t see the standard purple Appium server launch commands.
3. Powershell Start-Process command. "Start-Process appium -p 4723". Same impact as with 2.

Is there a way to verify that appium server exists?

I´m trying to achieve mobile app automated testing using Azure Repo&Pipelines, Robot Framework, Appium and Android studio emulator. For this purpose, I need Appium server running in the background. I´m doing the needed tool installations in my pipeline before entering to Appium running stage.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to verify that appium server exists?

Try command like `TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /V`.

For me, I use three cmd scripts (CMD task) to do the test, `task1 => npm install -g appium`, `task2 => start appium -p 4723`, `task3 => TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /V`. And here's the output of task3:

[image]

Since the `cmd.exe` will be killed when the task is done, so cmd.exe(task1) and cmd.exe(task2) doesn't exist.

Till the third task, only the newly created console (appium -p 4723) and the cmd.exe(task3) do exist. And the `appium -p 4723` is what you want, it do exist in background if we don't kill it.

**Note:**

1.I used the **second** command `start appium -p 4723` to test. It's expected behavior that your **first** command would start the server but it stays in the Cmdline job forever. Azure Devops pipeline won't go to next task, if current task hasn't completed. So if the cmd task is one listener that keeps running, it stays in the Cmdline task forever till timeout.

Second command is better in Azure Devops pipeline environment.

2.What you use is [microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops), it will be recovered when the pipeline is completed. So your appium listener will be killed after the the job/pipeline completes.

3.About Appium test in Azure Devops, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin#appium).

Answer (score 0):

with powershell command, I can start appium, try below code:

`- powershell: Start-Process appium -PassThru 4723 displayName: "start appium process"`

Answer (score 0):

After starting the appium server in azure devops, it cant execute the next task. I want after starting the server, next task will be executed.